# Solving simple ODE using scipy odeint gives straight line at 0

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, odeint

I am trying to solve a simple ODE: 
**dN/dt = N*(rho(t)-beta)/lambda**

Rho is a function of time and I've generated it using linspace. The code is working for other equations but somehow gives a flat straight line at 0. (You can see it in the graph). Any guidelines about how to correct it?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def model2(N, t, rho):
    beta_val = 0.0065
    lambda_val = 0.00002
    k = (rho - beta_val) / lambda_val
    dNdt = k*N
    print(rho)
    return dNdt

# initial condition
N0 = [0]

# number of time points
n = 200

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,200,n)

rho = np.linspace(6,9,n)
#rho =np.array([6,6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.9,7.0,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6,7.7,7.8,7.9])  # Array of constants

# store solution
NSol = np.empty_like(t)
# record initial conditions
NSol[0] = N0[0]

# solve ODE
for i in range(1,n):
    # span for next time step
    tspan = [t[i-1],t[i]]
    # solve for next step
    N = odeint(model2,N0,tspan,args=(rho[i],))
    print(N)
    # store solution for plotting
    NSol[i] = N[0][0]
    # next initial condition
    #z0 = N0[0]

# plot results
plt.plot(t,rho,'g:',label='rho(t)')
plt.plot(t,NSol,'b-',label='NSol(t)')
plt.ylabel('values')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[This is the graph I get after running this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T53vC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code (and the coefficients) to make it work. 
When coefficients are also dependent of `t`, they have to be python functions called by the derivative function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define
def model2(N, t, rho):
    beta_val = 0.0065
    lambda_val = 0.02
    k = ( rho(t) - beta_val )/lambda_val
    dNdt = k*N
    return dNdt

def rho(t):
    return .001 + .003/20*t


# Solve
tspan = np.linspace(0, 20, 10)
N0 = .01
N = odeint(model2, N0 , tspan, args=(rho,))

# Plot
plt.plot(tspan, N, label='NS;ol(t)');
plt.ylabel('N');
plt.xlabel('time'); plt.legend(loc='best');
```

Comment: This is working perfectly, but I want to use rho from the range I defined in my code i.e., 6-9, and I couldn't find a way to use it.

Comment: I think the error comes from the values used, the solution of `dN/dt = k*N` with k constant is `exp(k*t)`, and if `rho ~ 6`, `k` is about `3e6`, thus `N(200)~ exp(1e8)`...